# Accessing UI thread from Windows Runtime Component throws exception only on Mobile

Tags: c#, webview, uwp, ui-thread, winrt-component

I have the following problem. 
I am using a simple Windows Runtime Component to communicate between the application and a `WebView`. I am doing this [according to documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.addweballowedobject)

This is the code for the Windows Runtime Component

```
 public delegate void NotifyAppHandler( string str );

[AllowForWeb]
public sealed class WebViewInjectionObject
{
    public event NotifyAppHandler OnNotifyApp;

    public void NotifyApp( string str )
    {
        OnNotifyApp?.Invoke( str );
    }
}
```

In the `OnNavigatedTo` method I initialize the `WebViewInjectionObject` and subscribe to the `OnNotifyApp` event.

```
 webViewInjectionObject = new WebViewInjectionObject();
 webViewInjectionObject.OnNotifyApp += WebViewInjectionObject_OnNotifyApp;
```

Then on the `NavigationStarting` event of the `WebView` I call `AddWebAllowedObject` on the `WebView`

```
 private void WebView_NavigationStarting( WebView sender, WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs args ) {
        sender.AddWebAllowedObject( "nativeObject", webViewInjectionObject );
    }
```

The code in the `WebViewInjectionObject_OnNotifyApp` method which then interacts with the WebView looks like this.

```
if (somethingGood) {
    await WebView.InvokeScriptAsync( successFunctionName, functionArguments ); 
}
```

When running this on the Desktop (Version 1709, Build 16299.371) everything works fine.

When running this on the mobile phone (Version 1709 and Version 1607) I get this exception.

**The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))**

Usually esceptions like this are solved by using the dspatcher to make the call from the UI thread. I tried doing the followig

```
 await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync( Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
      {
           await WebView.InvokeScriptAsync( successFunctionName, functionArguments );
      } );
```

But this lead to a deeper exception

**A COM call to an ASTA was blocked because the call chain originated in or passed through another ASTA. This call pattern is deadlock-prone and disallowed by apartment call control.
A COM call (IID: {638BB2DB-451D-4661-B099-414F34FFB9F1}, method index: 6) to an ASTA (thread 3036) was blocked because the call chain originated in or passed through another ASTA (thread 5964). This call pattern is deadlock-prone and disallowed by apartment call control.**

After that I thought of using the `SynchronizationContext` so I did this.
In `OnNavigatedTo`

```
syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
```

And then in `WebViewInjectionObject_OnNotifyApp`

```
 syncContext.Post( async delegate
        {
             await WBTWebView.InvokeScriptAsync( successFunctionName, functionArguments );
        }, null );
```

This leads again to the first exception.

I am at a loss at what to do next. The goal is to catch the event thrown from the Windows Runtime Component and then call `InvokeScriptAsync` on the `WebView` in a way that works both for Desktop and Mobile.

Comment: Did you still have the issue in your environment? Did you use any alter ways currently?

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT  We ended up using a completely different approach in the end. This problem was not resloved. Here is a [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah9k2k7dg6rCkhXfay8-YHHBEzne) to a repro project if you need it. And a [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/228385cb-a894-42d2-9fec-9314cbee2789/a-com-call-to-an-asta-was-blocked-exception-from-windows-runtime-component-only-in-mobile?forum=wpdevelop) in msdn

Comment: We will report it. Thanks for feeding back.

Comment: @SunteenWu Has this been "reported"? Can you please link to the report here?